Per-project and global fallback config for shell scripts
I have some shell functions that I use for personal development. I would like to create config files on a per-project basis so that the functions read the config file and use values from the config file, if present.
This is a very basic example:
path/to/project/functions.sh (works)
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PROJECT_KEY="abc"

function project_name() {
  if [ -f .config ]; then
    . .config
  fi

  echo $PROJECT_KEY # => "def"
}

path/to/project/.config
PROJECT_KEY="def"

The above works, but I have dozens of these utility/helper functions, and I wanted to load the config via another function if it exists.
path/to/project/functions.sh (does not work)
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function load_config() {
  if [ -f .config ]; then
    . .config
  elif [ -f ~/.config ]; then
    . ~/.config
  fi
}

function project_name() {
  load_config

  echo $PROJECT_KEY # => "abc"
}

I believe that the load_config() function is sourcing the config file into the load_config() function, and then when that function returns/exits, the sourced variables are gone because they are scoped to the individual function call, ie, the load_config() function.
I understand my current approach isn't working, but I don't know how to avoid executing source .config all over the place. I want to put it in a single function that is called.
How do I cleanly read config files in my functions without a ton of duplicate code?
Update 2024-05-14 17:00 EST
I got a "working" version, here's the updated code. But this still seems very clunky.
function config_file() {
  if [[ -f .config ]]; then
    echo .config
  elif [[ -f $HOME/.config ]]; then
    echo $HOME/.config
  fi
}

function project_name() {
  [[ -f $(config_file) ]] && source $(config_file)

  echo $PROJECT_KEY # => outputs the value from the config file...
}


Variables aren't local to the function unless you use the local command to declare them.

Are you sure it's sourcing the files you expect? Add echo statements to the .config files so you know which ones are being sourced.

@Fravadona That was a typo on my part, I updated the question with the proper -f test.

Check the script with shellcheck and address any findings. . "~/.config" looks suspicious because tilde expansion does not occur within quotes.

@tjm3772 The quotes were removed in an edit 10 minutes before your comment.

. .config is not . ./.config, just like ls is not ./ls

I updated with a "working" example at the bottom. I can fix bad syntax issues, but my issue is I don't know how to approach solving a problem like this conceptually. Most of the online/google examples were sourcing a file in a single script, but I want to be able to source in multiple functions as needed.

How is PROJECT_KEY defined? Is it with declare PROJECT_KEY=foo?

@Fravadona It is just set in the main script file itself as PROJECT_KEY="value" and then in the .config files it is overwritten the same way with a new value. I'm not partial to that approach, it's just the only way I knew how to set and overwrite values in shell script. Any sort of key/value approach is fine with me.

Using declare could become an issue (or a feature) when you source the file from a function; those "declared" variables would then become local variables of the function.

BTW, why do you source the config from inside a function? Sourcing the it at the top of the script is the most common approach

I have a single file developer_utilities.sh that contains a bunch of useful functions for development. I source this file in my .bashrc file so I have access to them everywhere. Some of the functions do things like prefix git commits with a project name. Up until now, I've only had to work on 1 project at a time, so the script file could have the PROJECT_KEY="abc" set at the top of the file and it worked fine. What I want to do now is execute the functions for the config specified in the project directory now.

So you execute those function while being in the folder that contains the .config file? Then you might modify your cd command to make it load the config when you cd into that directory

Correct, when I execute the functions they should read the .config file if it exists in the directory they are executed in, otherwise they use the defaults. I'm hesitant to overwrite a default command like cd; is that a convention for a situation like this? I'm hoping to share this script file with other developers on my team, and I want to avoid unexpected side effects if possible.

Well, I can't recommend overloading your cd command as it might become dangerous if you're not aware of it. But no, I don't see a good way the solve your problem; sourcing the config file over and over seems like a waste though

It works fine here, project_name prints def, not abc. Edit your question with a reproducible example
